# Firemonkey sound when pressing enter on OSX

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi XE8, Firemonkey multi-device form.

In a standard TEdit set up for a password input, I'm unable to stop the default alert sound when the user presses enter (on OSX), Windows works fine.

I've tried setting the following in the KeyDown and KeyUp events:

```
procedure TfrmMain.txtPasswordPromptKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkReturn) and (btnPasswordPromptGo.Tag = 0) then begin
    Key := vkNone;
    KeyChar := #0;
    btnPasswordPromptGoClick(sender);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.txtPasswordPromptKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkReturn) and (btnPasswordPromptGo.Tag = 0) then begin
    Key := vkNone;
    KeyChar := #0;
  end;
end;
```

The sound still plays on OSX. Does anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: In a VCL application, you wouldn't need to write any of that code. You'd just set the `Default` property on the OK button to true. Does FMX not work that way?

Comment: Wow, in all the years of using the Cancel and Default properties, I never realized that it would prevent the default beep from a textbox as well! Thanks, that works. Turns out I overlooked that because I was using a TCornerButton which doesn't have the Default property, but I was able to change it to just a TButton.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `vknone` for your Key value, instead just set your result to 0. That should prevent the beep.

```
procedure TfrmMain.txtPasswordPromptKeyDown(Sender: TObject;
  var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkReturn) and (btnPasswordPromptGo.Tag = 0) then begin
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Also as Rob mentioned, you could set your Default property to true for the button you want executed when return is encountered. If you do this, you should not need the code that eats the carriage return.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I originally tried. It works on Windows and modal forms on the Mac, but not on the main form. The default property does work though.